# How do I select all of the tr's except the last two tr's

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, except

In lxml, I'm using xpath to select all of the tr's in a table (that has varying number of rows) except for the last two rows which contain gibberish.

Is there a pattern match that excludes the last two rows? I was looking through xpath tutorials and apparently there is an "except" operator and also a "last()," but can't seem to get my code working.

So far I have this. What do I add to this pattern to make it exclude the last two rows? The main problem is the number of tr's vary.

```
result = doc.xpath("//tr")
```

I guess I could turn this into a list and just remove the last two elements, but is there any easier/elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a pure XPath solution (a single one-liner expression) that selects all the wanted `tr` elements. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = doc.xpath("//tr")[0:-2]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

**Use**:

```
expressionSelectingTheTable/tr[not(position() > last() -2)]
```

where `expressionSelectingTheTable` should be substituted with a specific XPath expression that selects the table, for which the question is being asked (such as `//table[@id='foo']`)

This single XPath expression selects all `tr` children of the `table` parent, whose position is not one of the last two.

Comment: Hm interesting, didn't know you could do position() > last(). I thought you could only have one or the other. Thanks!

Comment: @chesspro: It is actually `not(position() > last() -2)` , and yes, the `position()` and `last()` functions can take part in *any* XPath expression. Expressions like `not(position() = last())` are used very often.